# Namespacing standards in javascript

Tags: javascript, namespaces

Can someone please explain what these lines of code are doing? And do I need them? Are there any benefits of having it this way? I understand the code inside. I just need help on the first line of code and the last line where it's being passed as a parameter to the self invoking function.

First Line: app.framework.resetHeadingsHierarchy = {};

Last Line: app.framework.resetHeadingsHierarchy, jQuery

Full code snippet:

```
app.framework.resetHeadingsHierarchy = {};
(function () {
    $(function() {
        let isPortletTitleBarHidden = $('.portlet-header-bar');

        if (isPortletTitleBarHidden.length === 0) {
            if ($('h4')) {
                $('h4').replaceWith(function () {
                    return '<h3>' + $(this).html() + '</h3>';
                });
            }
            if ($('h5')) {
                $('h5').replaceWith(function () {
                    return '<h4>' + $(this).html() + '</h4>';
                });
            }
        }
    });
})(app.framework.resetHeadingsHierarchy, jQuery);
```

Comment: The whole thing doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Every variable in there is loaded from a jQuery accessor.  Even `$(this)` is inside the `$('h4')` accessor.  Therefore you don't need any namespace code, since every variable is loaded from the dom.  You only need namespace if a global JavaScript variable may have the same name as another.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping a function in `$`, like `$(function(){})`, is just another way of calling an anonymous function after the DOM loads, or immediately if the DOM has already loaded. If you want to execute a function immediately, you can also do `(function(){})()` but that won't wait for the DOM

The other outer wrapper isn't doing anything useful as far as I can tell, the one that says `(function () {})(app.framework.resetHeadingsHierarchy, jQuery);`

Comment: oh, oops. I'll fix it

Comment: Do I even need the outermost function wrapper then since it appears that there is already an inner one which I believe is jQuerys version of a self invoking function.

$(function() {}

Comment: And "let isPortletTitleBarHidden" will always be protected meaning it can never be overridden by another variable with the same name since it is inside the anonymous function correct?

Comment: Something like that. `let` is block-scoped while `var` is function-scoped, and you cannot re-`let` the same variable within the same scope. Try this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s5hu9cy7/

Comment: You can reassign a `let` variable, but you cannot say `let` again in the same scope -- you can in an inner scope. So `let a = 2; a = 3;` will work. `const` won't even let you reassign.